# Twitter streaming API returns hangup

Tags: python, twitter

I built a Python app this spring which was meant to keep running monitoring public stream and collect tweets about certain topics. The code worked fine but now when I wanted to continue it, I keep getting {hangup: True} response if the stream doesn't get tweets almost constantly. I haven't been able to figure out what has changed and what I should do to fix the problem.

I'm using sixohsix's Twitter library: https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter
And below is my code for monitoring the stream:

```
q = 'huuhkajat' # Comma-separated list of terms
print sys.stderr, 'Filtering the public timeline for track="%s"' % (q,)

api = authTwitter.getApi()
mongodb = DatabaseHandler()
analyze = Analysis(mongodb.getDictionary())

# Reference the self.auth parameter
twitter_stream = twitter.TwitterStream(auth=api.auth) # See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis
stream = twitter_stream.statuses.filter(track=q)

try:
    i = 0
    for tweet in stream:
        print tweet
        if 'lang' in tweet.keys() and tweet['lang'] == 'fi':
            print tweet['text'] + " " + tweet['lang']
            print tweet['place']
            analyze.analyseTweet(tweet)

            if i % 1 == 0:
                print
                analyze.printStatistics()
                entry = {'positive' : analyze.getPositivePercent(), 'negative' : analyze.getNegativePercent(), 'neutral' : analyze.getNeutralPercent(), '_id' : 'sentimentPercentages', 'totalCount' : analyze.getCount(), 'latestTweet' : tweet, 'query' : q}
                mongodb.saveToDb(entry, mongodb.statisticCollection)
                mongodb.storeToDb(tweet, q) #tallentaa collectioniin jonka nimi on hakusana
                print
            i += 1
except twitter.TwitterHTTPError, e:

    f = open('streamErrors.log','w')
    f.write(e.message+'\n')
    f.close()
    print "ERROR " + e.message
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was cause by slightly old twitter library. By updating it via pip the script seems to work as in the past.

Answer (score 0):

If your analysis takes too long, Twitter will hangup on you.
Maybe your program isn't fast enough to process the sampler feed in realtime?
How long does your program need for analysis and storage in MongoDB?

Consider just dumping a number of records for analysis, and processing them from disk instead of live.

Comment: Actually that's not the problem. The problem seems to be that I don't get tweets fast enough for the connection since I'm looking for tweets on relatively rare topic (because they are in Finnish). So I don't even analyze anything. I suppose that something has changed in how I should keep the connection alive even if there is no tweets coming constantly.